# Not able to use Actuator in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We have a Spring Boot application with Spring Security enabled. Whenever we try to hit  */actuator/health* we get the

```
Whitelabel Error Page -There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)
```

We have the following in *application.properties*

> management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info
>
> management.security.enabled=false
>
> management.security.roles=AMDIN

and in *pom.xml*

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Followed this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators).
Is there any other role or something which we need to enable ?

Comment: Which spring boot version are you using.

Comment: @M.Deinum it's 1.5.2. Updated in the answer as well.

Comment: Then it should be `/health` unless you changed the URL for endpoints.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank You. It worked..